# Button Onclick works with api 25 but fails with api 18 - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-intent

It fails on the `intent = new intent()` line. Please help me thanks.

```
Intent intent;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

}

public void buttonTapped(View view){
    int id = view.getId();
    String ourId = "";
    ourId = view.getResources().getResourceEntryName((id));

    intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), aboutUsActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);

    //Log.i("button tapped", ourId);
}
```

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
>                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
>                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>                      Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
>                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240) 
>                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
>                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
>                      Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>                         at com.kshakoor.iiql.MainActivity.buttonTapped(MainActivity.java:68)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
>                         at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
>                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240) 
>                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730) 
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737) 
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
>                         at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Application terminated.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.kshakoor.iiql.MainActivity.buttonTapped(MainActivity.java:68)`

Comment: i added more code and detailed expcetion. i am not getting answer  for exception on new intent.

Comment: Try doing `intent = new Intent(*this*, aboutUsActivity.class);`